# scrollbar won't go away in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and no matter how much content is on the page there is always a scrollbar that appears to the right. Even turning on overflow-hidden doesn't make it go away. The page has nothing but a header, a link, and a panel. How can it be removed?

The HTML is roughly as follows:

```
<body>
<!-- Document framework -->
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="toolmenu" data-theme="a">
        <form>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Select Tool:</legend>
                <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
                <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">One</label>
                <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="off" type="radio">
                <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">Two</label>
                <input name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="other" type="radio">
                <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">Three</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Stuff<br />
        <a href="#toolmenu">Open panel link</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your HTML, this is simply not enough. This is not a standard jQuery Mobile behavior and we need an example so we can recreate your problem.

Comment: Added html. Is this enough? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue was that I had the css files in the wrong order. When you are using a custom theme with jquery mobile, you have to have the css files in a particular order--namely, your themeroller-created custom theme has to come BEFORE the jquery mobile css, and you have to use jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css (or the equivalent for whatever version you are using anyway), not the full css file.